# show field name with [] icon in django template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Here is my data That I want to show in my django page template

`<QueryDict: {'department': ['cb6594f8-b7a3-4319-b413-9b5ec8abeebb'], 'icd_code': ['54654ICDCODE'], 'value[]': ['450', '500', '120'], 'page_type': ['abcd'], 'service_code': ['56XRFT'], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['Hpg1qF9w2mP7ikJbj8NLLFcrygWdO9Q429cNKRHkIjm7B67BHOBGCNSR9DiAUAle'], 'billing_code[]': ['78984', 'AWEXZ67', 'POKIJH29'], 'key[]': ['Special', 'AC Room', 'first'], 'package_name': ['e2e9e4d3-0ebb-4343-96e3-710a6904057e']}>`

let this data is stored in variable name "formdata"
Then if I want to show the department then just show using {{formdata.department}}
But If I want to show the service_code then code should be 
Either `{{formdata.service_code}}`
or 
`{{formdata.service_code[]}}`
Or

```
{% for service_bill in formdata.service_code %}
   {{service_bill}}
{% endfor %}
```

But Unable to show data using any above method
Please suggest

Comment: Django doesn't treat keys like `key[]` any differently to `key`. The easiest solution might be to change your JavaScript to use keys without square brackets. For example, [in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/), you do this by setting `traditional` to true.

Comment: Actually the content that is coming back to page template is coming using `formdata = request.POST` and `key[]` is a checkbox field. That's why the field name is `key[]` instead of `key` , I could not rename it like `key` .

Comment: You should be able to change the value from `key[]` to `key` on the page you submit from. You haven’t shown the template/JavaScript that explains where that `request.POST` comes from, so I can’t be more specific.